# R session aborted on Ubuntu when using python-reticulate

Tags: python, ubuntu, rstudio, reticulate

I am struggling with `reticulate`. All the time I try to run some `python` code in a python script, I get the following error.

[image]

I have tried everything! Latest Rstudio, R, reticulate, Rcpp, Python.... nothing works. I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is some additional information.

```
> library(reticulate)
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Pop!_OS 21.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.24

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.3  Matrix_1.4-0    tools_4.1.3     Rcpp_1.0.8.3    grid_4.1.3      jsonlite_1.8.0 
[7] png_0.1-7       lattice_0.20-45
> 
> py_discover_config()
python:         /usr/bin/python3
libpython:      /usr/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so
pythonhome:     //usr://usr
version:        3.9.7 (default, Sep 10 2021, 14:59:43)  [GCC 11.2.0]
numpy:          /home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.22.3

python versions found: 
 /usr/bin/python3
 /home/ahmed/.virtualenvs/r-test/bin/python
 /home/ahmed/virtualReph/bin/python
```

I have also tried to run reticulate directly from R (and not RStudio), and that's what I get:

```
> library(reticulate)
> Sys.which("python3")
           python3 
"/usr/bin/python3" 
> use_python("/usr/bin/python3")
> os <- import("os")

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x90, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,     config$virtualenv_activate, config$version >= "3.0", interactive(),     numpy_load_error)
 2: (function() {    Sys.setenv(PYTHONPATH = newpythonpath)    on.exit(Sys.setenv(PYTHONPATH = oldpythonpath), add = TRUE)    py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,         config$virtualenv_activate, config$version >= "3.0",         interactive(), numpy_load_error)})()
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch({    oldpythonpath <- Sys.getenv("PYTHONPATH")    newpythonpath <- Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_PYTHONPATH", unset = paste(config$pythonpath,         system.file("python", package = "reticulate"), sep = .Platform$path.sep))    local({        Sys.setenv(PYTHONPATH = newpythonpath)        on.exit(Sys.setenv(PYTHONPATH = oldpythonpath), add = TRUE)        py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,             config$virtualenv_activate, config$version >= "3.0",             interactive(), numpy_load_error)    })}, error = function(e) {    Sys.setenv(PATH = oldpath)    if (is.na(curr_session_env)) {        Sys.unsetenv("R_SESSION_INITIALIZED")    }    else {        Sys.setenv(R_SESSION_INITIALIZED = curr_session_env)    }    stop(e)})
 7: initialize_python(required_module, use_environment)
 8: ensure_python_initialized(required_module = module)
 9: import("os")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```